# has_one / belongs_to not loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I think it's because of how my Proposal model is set up but I'm not sure how to get around it.

JSON Response

```
{
  "proposal":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "proposee_id":1,
      "proposer_id":4
    }
  ],
  "user":{
    "id":4,
    "username":"rawr",
    "email":"rawr@ar.com",
    "proposal_id":1
  }
}
```

proposal model (Ember)

```
App.Proposal = DS.Model.extend
    proposer: DS.belongsTo "user"
    proposee: DS.belongsTo "user"
    status: DS.attr "string"
```

Proposal Model (Rails)

```
class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :proposer, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :proposee, class_name: "User"
end
```

User model (Ember)

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend
  username: DS.attr 'string'
  email: DS.attr 'string'
  password: DS.attr 'string'
  password_confirmation: DS.attr 'string'
  proposal: DS.belongsTo "proposal"
```

User model (Rails - truncated)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :encrypt_password

    attr_accessor :password

    has_one :proposal_to, class_name: "Proposal", foreign_key: "proposer_id"
    has_one :proposal_from, class_name: "Proposal", foreign_key: "proposee_id"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why.
I had to change `proposal_id` in the JSON response to `proposal`.
The change was made in Ember-Data 1.0.0Beta and is addressed [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1173)